# Spring Shedlock does not ensure synchronization

Tags: java, spring, shedlock

I have following scheduled job which runs in multiple instances.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
@SchedulerLock(name = "AwesomeJob", lockAtLeastForString = "5S", lockAtMostForString = "5S")
public void awesomeJob() throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        log.info("Processing {}", i);
        Thread.sleep(100000L);
    }
}
```

I know that If the task takes longer than lockAtMostFor the resulting behavior may be unpredictable. Is there a way to avoid that behavior by using SimpleLock.extend method? I am using JdbcLockProvider. I got this idea from https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/issues/151 .

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Are you running same scheduled jobs on many machines?

Comment: @sonus21 yes, I am running same scheduled job on many machines.  Actually, this is a code I implemented for testing purpose. Real one is intended to consume reports in a queue. Therefore I want high availability.

Comment: You are probably better of with using something like Quartz and a single instance job. Instead of trying to bolt something on top the the simple scheduling in Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually, this code is just for testing purposes. Real one is intended to consume reports in a queue. Therefore I want high availability and a single instance job will not be enough.

Comment: What is it you are trying to test then? Looks like an absurd test to do. You want a single instance of your test, but not in real code? What do you want to achieve with this if yuou aren't testing something you are going to use in production? Also if it is a queue why would you need a job at all? So why in test only execute a single instance of the job at once, while not in real?

Comment: I don't want a single instance. I want multiple instances. the difference between the real one and testing one is only the method body. I want to ensure that when this code runs in two different machines only one machine running this method while other one waits until previous one finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to set `lockAtMostFor` to a higher value. It's just a safety net for cases when the node executing the task dies so it should not be a problem.

If you can not do it for some reason, you can use `extend` method as described in the issue you provided. But it means you have to manage the lock manually. There is currently no functionality allowing to extend a lock created automatically using AOP.

Comment: Thaks :) That means I have to call extend method inside the job I want to synchronize. Is that correct? The other case is I cannot see extend method supporting JdbcLockProvider.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can give an example from JdbcLockProvider using extend method.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface LockService {
   bool aquireLock(String lockKey, String value);
   bool releaseLock(String lockKey);
}

interface SomeService {
   void do();
}

class Scheduler{
    @AutoWired LockService lockService;
    @Autowired SomeService someService;
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void awesomeJob() throws InterruptedException {
      if(lockService.aquireLock("awesomeJob", serverId) ){
        try{
           //call service method 
            someService.do();
        }catch( Exception e ){
          //TODO
        }finally{
          lockService.releaseLock("awesomeJob");
        }
      }   
    }
}
```

You can have a lock like this example, implement a lock interface that will provide a lock for the given service. Once you have LockService use that to restrict the function run.

The only problem with this is you need to add this code block to all functions. If you don't want to add this code block to all functions then add an annotation-based AOP  handler.

Also, what about if the server who had acquired lock dies? We need to set the maximum expiry time of each lock or use time in the lock value to identify when it was added, based on the lock time make a decision whether this is possible to run or not.

Comment: how can this ensure same method runs in a different machine does not run the method?

Comment: That's what `acquireLock` method does, you can not acquire the lock when another machine has already acquired the lock.

Comment: acquiring happens based on serverId, right? Maybe I can use a db table to maintain that. am I right? Is there a way to do this by using shedlock?

Comment: acquiring happens based on the functionName, I'm not sure what `Shedlock` does and how it has been implemented, It's not too difficult to implement.

Comment: It's not like same method is accessed by different machines. the method runs in different machines. I mean this code part is deployed in different machines.  This is Shedlock. https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

Comment: @SachithraPathiraja It seems you don't understand, how SchedLock works, what feature it provides.  SchedLock requires you to provide a lock name, what does that mean? That simply means you're holding a lock with the given key name. Implement the same why are you depending on ShedLock?

Comment: Shedlock make a db entry with the lock name. and the other machine checks that entry.

Comment: You remove Shedlock and implement your own, Use that lock to restrict the function/code. block run.